# How can I migrate my database with rails to the first revision without dropping the database first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, rake

I have a database set up for my Rails installation and some migrations set up. I would like to be able to reset my database back down to having no tables/constraints/etc., but can't find a reasonable way to do this without knowing the number of migrations or the timestamp of the first migration. Here are my options as I see them:

- `rake db:migrate:reset`
- `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20090701154839` where 20090701154839 is the timestamp associated with the first migration
- `rake db:rollback STEP=15` where there have been 15 migrations

The problem with `db:migrate:reset` is that it drops the database first (it does `db:drop`, `db:create`, then `db:migrate`).

The problem with `db:migrate:down` is that I don't want to encode the VERSION of the beginning.

The problem with `db:rollback` is that I don't know the number of steps it is back to the beginning.

What are my options?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

It works even if you're using the newer timestamped migration files.

Update: I just tested this on Rails 3.2.1, and it still works. It runs the "down" part of all the migrations known to `schema_migrations`. I have no idea if it worked on 3.1 or not, but the comment below indicates that this feature was broken during that time.

Comment: Thank you; this is what I was looking for. I had tried rake:db:migrate:down VERSION=0, but down looks for particular versions, whereas db:migrate doesn't.

Comment: Does not work with rails 3.1.0 rc 4: `No migration with version number 0`

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune I had the same issue. Make sure you do `rake db:migrate VERSION=0' (I was doing db:migrate:down VERSION=0)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to jdl's (correct) solution above, another hack-y way to acheive this is to do `rake db:rollback STEP=1000000`, where `1000000` is a large number, larger than the number of migrations you'll ever have. It will rollback as far as it can up to `1000000` times, or however many times you put as the `STEP`.

Answer (score 0):

It's moderately hackish, but you could do a query to find the first VERSION in schema_migrations and then call rake db:migrate:down to get that VERSION (I'm assuming you want to package up a "reset" script for your app).

That will, of course, require that the down methods on all your migrations work properly.