# Rake task to truncate all tables in Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rake

I would like to have a rake task for truncating all the tables. I have [found one](http://www.manu-j.com/blog/truncate-all-tables-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application/221/) on the internet, but it is supposed only for Rails 2 and does not work for **Rails 3** (problem is in getting a database connection).

`rake db:reset` is not an option, because I am using PostgreSQL and it also drops the user. Therefore migration fails. I only want to clear the data.

Do you guys have somehting for me?

Comment: I've never seen a postgres user being dropped when doing a `db:reset`. Is my setup that radically different from yours?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've found this via google, and then I got a much simpler solution than the one approved, so here it is: Use the [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem. Here're the steps.

In your Gemfile (execute bundle after modifying):

```
gem 'database_cleaner' # you might want to limit this to the dev and staging group
```

With that gem in place, the statement `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation` will truncate the database. Adding it to a rake task is trivial:

```
# tasks/db/clean.rake

namespace :db do

  desc "Truncate all existing data"
  task :truncate => "db:load_config" do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

end
```

That's it. You can also use the `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation` line inside your `db/seeds.rb` file directly so that you don't forget to truncate the database before seeding.

Comment: The line in the seed file was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 19):

So I edited the linked example into this:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Truncate all existing data"
  task :truncate => "db:load_config" do
   begin
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[::Rails.env]
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    case config["adapter"]
      when "mysql", "postgresql"
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table}")
        end
      when "sqlite", "sqlite3"
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM #{table}")
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence where name='#{table}'")
        end                                                                                                                               
       ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("VACUUM")
     end
    end
  end
end
```

This example is based on Chris Ledet's code bellow (thanks) and works with **Rails 3.X**.

Thanks for all hints.

Comment: I've added this to make it work with mysql2 : `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table}") if table != "schema_migrations"`. And `when "mysql", "mysql2", "postgresql"` Otherwise, Rails wanted to migrate everything over again.

Comment: Ya there definitely needs to be a `unless table == 'schema_migrations'` on those truncate lines.

Comment: This crash when has foreign_keys in the tables

Answer (score 10):

According to Chris Ledet answer, this becomes much simpler:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE #{table};")
end
```

Answer (score 10):

**To truncate db in Rails 6**

```
rails db:truncate_all
```

Comment: And if you need to truncate the tables from within your application code you can use rails 6' ```ActiveRecord::Base.connection.truncate_tables```. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/82d7e3e21708dcb21b47198f996cf3ec9f372612/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb#L218.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.truncate_tables` didn't work. 
 I had to call `ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.truncate_all` instead. rails 6.0.2.2

Answer (score 6):

You could always migrate to version 0, like so:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

That way you don't even have to truncate your tables, and you can then migrate again. The only catch is that you need your `down` migrations to work properly.

This solution **does** work in rails 3, despite the fact that the versions are timestamp-based.

This solution is as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196822/241367

Additionally, you could always run the following, assuming your `schema.rb` is up to date:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

And as @kikito suggests, you can run `database_cleaner` (it's what `cucumber` and `rspec` like to use between tests) like so:

```
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
```

Comment: I like the idea of using db:schema:load. That is very clean and does exactly what I want which is to reset the database without having to drop and recreate.

Answer (score 3):

This will get all of the tables in your database, find a model associated with that table and call #[destroy_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all).

```
tables = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
tables.each do |tbl|
 # "users" => User
 tbl.classify.constantize.destroy_all
end
```

Comment: I'm more interested about the Rake task - how to implement it. The linked example only works with Rails 2.x. I am keeping trying that.

Comment: Wrong. This example works with Rails 3 and 3.1. Nothing is stopping you from putting it in a rake task.

Comment: Sorry but you did not provide information how to make a connection in Rails 3 (in a rake task). Its a big difference in Rails 2 and Rails 3.

Comment: I use 3.0.10 and 3.1 on a daily basis and this works. Just put it in a rake task and you'll do fine. If it's because I didn't wrap it in a rake task for you so you can just copy and pase it then oh well, I'm not here to spoon feed. This code works when included in a rake task body or rails runner script.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by lzap has one specific problem. Rails wants to run all the migrations again. The following code is as suggested by Anthony Alberto and it works. This addition checks with the schema_migrations table

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Truncate all existing data"
  task :truncate => "db:load_config" do
   begin
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[::Rails.env]
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    case config["adapter"]
      when "mysql", "postgresql"
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table}") if table != "schema_migrations"
        end
      when "sqlite", "sqlite3"
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM #{table}") if table != "schema_migrations"
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence where name='#{table}'") if table != "schema_migrations"
        end                                                                                                                               
       ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("VACUUM")
     end
    end
  end
end
```