# in rails 3.2 how can I clean all data from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't want to delete my database structure, but I want to empty it, is there a simple command to do that?

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for? [TRUNCATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755389/rake-task-to-truncate-all-tables-in-rails-3)

Comment: would it be:  "rails db truncate" ???

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure of this but try running rake -T on your project folder and see what task do you have.. you could try rake db:schema:load, if that doesn't work try with your own truncate task as stated ins [THIS EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755389/rake-task-to-truncate-all-tables-in-rails-3)