# Equivalent Heroku run rake in Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, unicorn

I use to have Heroku managing my Rails application deployment but now that I built my own server with Capistrano, Nginix and Unicorn.

In Heroku, when I want to run a rake task, I do this for example:

```
heroku run rake:migrate VERSION=0
```

How can I accomplish the same using Capistrano? I cannot seem to find a clear and easy solution.

Thank you.

Comment: This has been asked and answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312214/how-do-i-run-a-rake-task-from-capistrano

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
bundle exec RAILS_ENV=PRODUCTION rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

on the project's `current` directory.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196310/how-can-i-migrate-my-database-with-rails-to-the-first-revision-without-dropping) you can find more information on topic.