# NoMethodError in Eurekamoments#new | undefined method `field' for #<Eurekamoment:0x52c6f80>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Eurekamoments#new
undefined method `field' for #<Eurekamoment:0x52c6f80>
```

on this line:

```
 <%= f.text_field :field %>
```

from this view

```
  This is new view

<%= form_for(@eurekamoment) do |f| %>
  <% if @eurekamoment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@eurekamoment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @eurekamoment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :eurekamoment %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :eurekamoment %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :field %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :field %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller:

```
class EurekamomentsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @eurekamoment = Eurekamoment.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3 )
      params[:per_page] ||= 25
      params[:page]     ||= 1
    end

    def show
      @eurekamoment   = Eurekamoment.find(params[:id])
      @comment = Comment.new
      @vote = Vote.new
    end

    def new
      @eurekamoment = Eurekamoment.new
    end

    def create
      @eurekamoment = Eurekamoment.new(link_params)
        if @eurekamoment.save
            redirect_to @eurekamoment 
        else
            render action: 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
      @eurekamoment = Eurekamoment.find(params[:id])
      if @eurekamoment.destroy
        redirect_to action: 'index'
      else
        render action: 'show'
      end
    end

    def edit
      @eurekamoment = Eurekamoment.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
    @eurekamoment = Eurekamoment.find params[:id]
      if @eurekamoment.update(eurekamoment_params)
        redirect_to @eurekamoment 
      else
        render action: 'edit'
      end
    end

private
    def eurekamoment_params
      params.require(:eurekamoment).permit(:id, :eurekamoment, :field, :description, :plan)
    end


end
```

This is my model:

```
class Eurekamoment < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :votes

end
```

And my db:

```
class CreateEurekamoments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :eurekamoments do |t|

            t.integer :user_id
            t.string  :field
            t.string  :eurekamoment
            t.string  :description
            t.string  :plan

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I've wasted last hour trying to figure this out at a hackathon and can't fix this issue, do you guys see anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you run rake db:migrate? Does the field "field" exist in your DB?

Comment: Nothing happens when I run rake db:migrate its weird. I have a field in my db but not sure it got added? It seems my rake db:migrate is perhaps not working

Comment: I ran a rake db:reset just before this and I think that might ave messed it up. What can I do to get my migrations working again.?

Comment: saw in my schema that my fields table wasn't forming so I forced the migration to re-run and then it made the table but I still get the same error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good - the error will almost certainly be a DB issue, as discussed in your comments

I think this will be the *real* cause of your problem: `I've wasted last hour trying to figure this out at a hackathon and can't fix this issue` -- it's best to take a step back, deep breath and work through it logically

I'd start with a total db refresh. Drop your tables & then run `rake db:migrate` again, or you could use `rake db:migrate VERSION=0`, or `rake db:migrate:reset` - [How can I migrate my database with rails to the first revision without dropping the database first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196310/how-can-i-migrate-my-database-with-rails-to-the-first-revision-without-dropping)